# Suggestion for calling Java from database triggers

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, distributed-system

We have Oracle SQL, and SQL Server. Both runs on different servers. We would like to make a database triggers that will call a Java method. The Java web server which is running in another server in the Docker container environment. After reading some online docs as follows I found it is possible.

Oracle SQL : https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/jjdev/calling-Java-from-database-triggers.html#GUID-5C498DEF-0348-484D-AA26-2A88EF348D5C

SQL Server: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/language-extensions/how-to/call-java-from-sql?view=sqlallproducts-allversions

So I am not sure which way to go ahead with this distributed system. Is it RMI or something else? Please suggest to me what to do?

Comment: I would suggest starting with an actual question. Nobody can suggest anything to you because we have no idea what you want to do other than call some java from oracle and/or sql server which you have provided links to solutions for both of those.

Comment: It is not a question for any technical problems. It is more like a suggestion to implement my scenario.

Comment: We don't know what your scenario is other than an extremely vague overview.